# Qt OpenGL GUI: Add and Undo Qpushbutton

Tags: qt, user-interface, opengl, undo

On my mainwindow I have two Qpushbuttons: add object button and undo button.

When I click the add object button, it renders an OpenGL model, and I want it to render another model when I click the add button again. The Undo button should undo the last add-action.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'd assume `C++`? Take a look at [events and signals](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/qt4tutorial/eventsandsignals/).

Comment: So you just want to go back and forth between the elements of a set of meshes? (probably with a wrap-around when going over the end?). Doesn't really seems like an OpenGL or Qt question if that's the case.

Comment: This is about basic GUI programming. First, you need to be able to do *something* when a particular button is pressed. It doesn't matter what; just get the detection part to work. Then, you need to figure out how to have multiple models that are rendered, such that you can add to and remove from the list. Finally, you can hook that concept up to the add/remove buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OpenGL model, and I want it to render another model when I click the add button again.

You're confusing OpenGL with a scene graph. OpenGL does not maintain a scene of objects or geometry. I just draw's things. If you change something, you've to redraw the whole thing from the scene data you maintain.

Undo/Redo become operations on your scene data. And after the operations on the scene you can use OpenGL do draw the scene.

Comment: Thanks. I connected the Add button to call a function that draws the scene with an object, then I connected the Undo button to re-draw the scene without that object. Looks okay! But now, how do I make the Add button to draw different objects at each click, say I click first, it adds object1, i click second time and it adds object 2. Then I click Undo, and it re draws scene with only object 1, then I click undo again and it draws scene without any object ?

Answer (score 0):

Qt has an entire [framework](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qundo.html) dedicated to undo/redo stacks.